How to add Anaconda Prompt option to Windows Terminal?
How can I add an Anaconda Prompt option to Windows Terminal?
I have installed Anaconda Navigator. I do not have any other Python distributions installed. This is a Windows 11 system, but the same information should apply to any other Windows system with Windows Terminal installed.
Here is a screenshot of my current Windows Terminal environment options:


Step 1 - Find directory containing Anaconda Prompt shortcut
Press Windows Key or otherwise open Start Menu search.
Search for Anaconda. You should see search results for Anaconda Prompt and Anaconda Powershell Prompt. It does not matter which one you choose, since both shortcuts exist in the same directory.
Click on Open file location

Step 2 - Copy Target from Properties
You should find a File Explorer window has been opened to the directory
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)

Right click either Anaconda Prompt or Anaconda Powershell Prompt. Select Properties.
Copy the path in Target. It should be something like this:
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3


Step 3 - Duplicate and Modify existing Windows Terminal Profile
Open Windows Terminal, and select Settings from the drop down arrow next to the currently open tab.
Select Add a new profile.
Duplicate either the Command Prompt or Windows Powershell profile depending on which option you chose in the previous step.


Change the name to Anaconda
Replace the current contents of the Command line configuration to the command copied from the Target in the previous step
As an added bonus, you can change the icon to the Anaconda Navigator icon if you wish. You can find the path to this icon by right clicking the Anaconda Navigator shortcut link from the previous step and selecting Change Icon



